# Do you need to store your old data to refit a model in sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-fitting

I am trying to use sklearn to build an Isolation Forest machine learning program to go through a ton of data. I can only store the past 10 days of data, so I was wondering:

When I use the "fit" function on new data that comes in, does it refit the model considering the hyper-parameters from the old data **without having had access to that old data anymore**? Or is it completely recreating the model?

Answer (score 0):

In general, only the estimators implementing the `partial_fit` method are able to do this. Unfortunately, `IsolationForest` is not one of them.

Comment: Are there any you know of that would be particularly good for anomaly detection?